# Program to display/rewrite/reformat log file in the terminal

Tags: editors, logging, terminal-output

I usually compile my `.tex` files from the terminal without the `-interaction=nonstopmode`, so that it stops at every error, but of course I still need to look at the `.log` file from time to time, but mostly it is only to find bad boxes, undefined references and other warnings.

My question is, does anyone know of a program, a script or some method to display the log file in a terminal, in a reformated way which is more readable, like some TeXeditors do.

Just to add some examples of what could be nice.  It would be nice if it couted how many errors, warning and bad boxes there where, maybe even the number of unknown references as well.  It would probably also be nice it used a small amount of colors (when in a color terminal), to make things easier to distinguish.  These things are done by TeXmaker, and it even produces a list telling you in which file the problem is, if it is a warning, a bad box an error, etc., gives you the line number and the message given by TeX.  It would be really nice if something like that was possible in the terminal.

Comment: Did you look at `texloganalyser`? It's a script included in TeX Live.

Comment: @egreg:  I did not know about `texloganalyser`, but as far as I can se it does not really make it that easy to read.  That it always displays the page numbers is a bit confusing, and it does not show errors at all.  Besides that it is a tool I had not seen, and it might be handy in some other connections :)